# Receiving a text file instead of html file In Django

Tags: python, html, django

I currently have a model named Order in models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
   order_item = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   order_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.order_name
```

In the views.py file I have

```
def ordering(request):
   latest_order = Order.objects.all()
   context = {'latest_order':latest_order}
   return render(request, 'users/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering'}, context)
```

I wanted to show the orders on the html page but all im getting back is a txt file

[image: Django's Output]

Is there a better approach for me to keep track of a user's order?

Comment: I think your render should be: ```render(request, 'users/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering', 'latest_order': latest_order})```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Django's documentation, the fourth parameter of render function is [content type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). Which basically tells Django the MIME type of the response. By default that is set to "text/html".

However, in your case you are passing (`render(request, 'users/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering'}, context)`) a dictionary as MIME type (the context variable). And I am guessing Django doesn't know what that type is so its just displaying the rendered output as text.

If you change your render function like this:

`render(request, 'users/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering', 'latest_order': latest_order})`

It should work properly :)

Also, welcome to SO :D

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!